# How to merge dataframes with dask without running out of memory?

Tags: python, dask

Merging multiple dask dataframes crashes my computer.

Hi,

I am attempting to merge a long list of csv files with dask. Each csv file contains a list of timestamps when a variable has changed its value, together with the value; e.g. for variable1 we have:

```
timestamp; value
2016-01-01T00:00:00; 3
2016-01-03T00:00:00; 4
```

while for variable 2, we have:

```
timestamp; value
2016-01-02T00:00:00; 8 
2016-01-04T00:00:00; 9
```

The timestamps in each csv can differ (as they are linked to the moment a variable has changed value). As end result, I want to obtain a hdf file in which each variable has as value at each occurring timestamp, forward filled. Hence, something like the following:

```
timestamp; var1; var2, 
2016-01-01T00:00:00; 3 ; nan
2016-01-02T00:00:00; 3 ; 8
2016-01-03T00:00:00; 4 ; 8
2016-01-04T00:00:00; 4 ; 9
```

Below, I provide the meta code which I am using to achieve this parsing and merging.

```
# import 
from pathlib import Path
from functools import partial
import import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.bag as db
from dask import delayed
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

# define how to parse the dates 
def parse_dates(df):
    return pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', errors='coerce')

# parse csv files to dask dataframe
def parse_csv2filtered_ddf(fn_file, sourcedir): 
    fn = source_dir.joinpath(fn_tag)
    ddf = dd.read_csv(fn, sep=';', usecols=['timestamp', 'value'], 
                      blocksize=10000000, dtype={'value': 'object'})
    meta = ('timestamp', 'datetime64[ns]')
    ddf['timestamp'] = ddf.map_partitions(parse_dates, meta=meta)
    v = fn_file.split('.csv')[0]
    ddf = ddf.dropna() \
        .rename(columns={'value': v}) \
        .set_index('timestamp')
    return ddf

# define how to merge
def merge_ddf(x, y):
    ddf = x.merge(y, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, npartitions=4)
    return ddf

# set source directory 
source_dir = Path('/path_to_list_of_csv_files/')

# get list of files to parse
lcsv = os.listdir(source_dir)

# make partial function to fix sourcedir  
parse_csv2filtered_ddf_partial = partial(parse_csv2filtered_ddf, source_dir)

# make bag of dataframes
b = db.from_sequence(lcsv).map(parse_csv2filtered_ddf_partial)

# merge all dataframes and reduce to 1 dataframe 
df = b.fold(binop=merge_ddf)

# forward fill the NaNs and drop the remaining
#
# please note that I am choosing here npartitions equal to 48 as 
#  experiments with smaller sets of data allow me to estimate 
#  the output size of the df which should be around 48 GB, hence 
#  chosing 48 should lead to partition of 1 GB, I guess. 
df = delayed(df).repartition(npartitions=48). \
    fillna(method='ffill'). \
    dropna()

# write output to hdf file
df = df.to_hdf(output_fn, '/data')

# start computation
with ProgressBar():
    df.compute(scheduler='threads')
```

Unfortunately, this scripts never runs to a successfull end. In particular, monitoring the memory usage I can follow the memory to fully flow up, after which either the computer or the program crashes.

I have tried to use only a single thread, in combination with multiple processes; e.g.

```
import dask
dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded')
```

in combination with

```
with ProgressBar():
    df.compute(scheduler='processes', num_workers=3)
```

also without any success.

Any pointers in the right direction are warmly welcomed.

**EDIT**

Below, I provide a more concise script which should allow to generate similar data to reproduce the MemoryError.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from dask import delayed
from dask import dataframe as dd
from dask import array as da
from dask import bag as db
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from functools import partial

def make_ddf(col, values, timestamps):
    n = int(col) % 2
    idx_timestamps = timestamps[n::2]
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({str(col): values, 'timestamp': idx_time})
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, chunksize=100000000)
    ddf = ddf.dropna() \
        .set_index('timestamp')
    return ddf

def merge_ddf(x, y):
    ddf = x.merge(y, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, npartitions=4)
    return ddf

N_DF_TO_MERGE = 55  # number of dataframes to merge 
N_PARTITIONS_REPARTITION = 55  

values = np.random.randn(5000000, 1).flatten()   
timestamps = [datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=i*1) for i in range(10000000)]  
columns = list(range(N_DF_TO_MERGE))

# fix values and times
make_ddf_partial = partial(make_ddf, values=values, timestamps=timestamps)

# make bag
b = db.from_sequence(columns).map(make_ddf_partial)

# merge all dataframes and reduce to one 
df = b.fold(binop=merge_ddf)

# forward fill the NaNs and drop the remaining
df = delayed(df).repartition(npartitions=N_PARTITIONS_REPARTITION). \
    fillna(method='ffill'). \
    dropna()

# write output to hdf file
df = df.to_hdf('magweg.hdf', '/data')

with ProgressBar():
    df.compute(scheduler='threads')
```

which leads up to the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "mcve.py", line 63, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in **call**
>       return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
>       rv = self.invoke(ctx)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
>       return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
>       return callback(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "mcve.py", line 59, in main
>       df.compute(scheduler='threads')
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 156, in compute
>       (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 398, in compute
>       results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 76, in get
>       pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 459, in get_async
>       raise_exception(exc, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\compatibility.py", line 112, in reraise
>       raise exc
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 230, in execute_task
>       result = _execute_task(task, data)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
>       return func(*args2)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\utils.py", line 697, in **call**
>       return getattr(obj, self.method)(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 1154, in to_hdf
>       return to_hdf(self, path_or_buf, key, mode, append, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\hdf.py", line 227, in to_hdf
>       scheduler=scheduler, **dask_kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 166, in compute_as_if_collection
>       return schedule(dsk2, keys, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py", line 76, in get
>       pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 459, in get_async
>       raise_exception(exc, tb)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\compatibility.py", line 112, in reraise
>       raise exc
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 230, in execute_task
>       result = _execute_task(task, data)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
>       return func(*args2)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\methods.py", line 103, in boundary_slice
>       result = getattr(df, kind)[start:stop]
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1500, in **getitem**
>       return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1867, in _getitem_axis
>       return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1536, in _get_slice_axis
>       return self._slice(indexer, axis=axis, kind='iloc')
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 151, in _slice
>       return self.obj._slice(obj, axis=axis, kind=kind)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3152, in _slice
>       result = self._constructor(self._data.get_slice(slobj, axis=axis))
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 700, in get_slice
>       bm._consolidate_inplace()
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 929, in _consolidate_inplace
>       self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1899, in _consolidate
>       _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3146, in _merge_blocks
>       new_values = np.vstack([b.values for b in blocks])
>     File "C:\Users\tomasvanoyen\Miniconda3\envs\stora\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 234, in vstack
>       return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
>   MemoryError

Comment: Please can you try to reduce the size of you example to the minimum nugget that demonstrates the problem? There are too many variables here. Also, since it may depend on the specifics of the data, a way to generate the data would be very helpful too.

Comment: Hi @mdurant, just a bump to ping that the question has been edited with a mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Two things seem odd.

1. You're calling dask dataframe code from within dask.bag code.
2. You seem to be calling merge when perhaps you just want concat?

Comment: Hi @MRocklin, thanks for your response.
Indeed, for our goal, the solution was to use `dask.dataframe.concat(list_of_dask_dataframes, axis=1)`. Nevertheless, the question remains why merging a bag of dask dataframes results in a MemoryError.